# Can information which has been overwritten with git commit --amend be exposed through git push?

Tags: git

I investigated a tricky issue and finally decided to create a SSCCE by reducing my closed source project step by step. In each step I verified that the issue occurs and committed to `git` with `git commit --amend`, i.e. there's only one commit. Now, I want to publish the SSCCE on a FLOSS code hosting platform like gitlab.com or github.com as public project.

Do I risk to expose any file content which has been overwritten with `git commit --amend`? The current commit which will be pushed can be considered save to publish.

I'm aware that I can delete the repository and recreate it locally. It's more of a question to learn.

Comment: If you want to be certain then create a new SSCCE that doesn't have a history and publish that instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Warning: this is a long answer; I did not have time to write a shorter one.  Parts were written between doing other things and there might be some semantic gaps in the text.)

There are multiple parts to this answer, but the short version is that `git push` normally pushes a minimal set of commits, which bring along for the ride a minimal set of trees and files.  That means that in normal cases you will be safe here.

It's the potential for abnormal cases that should concern you, and those could be sufficient reason to make a new repository with no other history.

Let's look first at what `git commit --amend` really does, because it does not actually amend any commits.  To get there, we have to start with how `git commit` works at a low level, which means looking at actual commits.

Here's one from the Git repository for Git:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
468165c1d8a442994a825f3684528361727cd8c0
$ git cat-file -p 468165c1d8a442994a825f3684528361727cd8c0 | sed 's/@/ /'
tree 6a54cb7c68d97e863a28478d728c58a1e47f0b4f
parent 1614dd0fbc8a14f488016b7855de9f0566706244
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1522689215 -0700
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1522689215 -0700

Git 2.17

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

This is a typical normal commit: like all commits, it has one `tree`, and like most but not all commits, it has one `parent` line.  It has an author and committer—each provide three pieces of information: name, email address, and timestamp—and it has a log message, which consists of all the lines past the first blank line.

The parent or parents tell Git which commits come *before* this commit.  Other commits may have two or more parents—these are *merge commits*—and at least one commit, the very first one you make in a repository, has *no* parent, because nothing comes before it.  The `parent` lines allow Git to chain commits together.  A commit with no parents is a *root* commit, where the chain ends.

The *files* for the commit are stored underneath the `tree` object, which is a bit large—here's just a part of it:

```
100644 blob 536e55524db72bd2acf175208aef4f3dfc148d42    COPYING
040000 tree ccab6cfb14e8e198eb4981fbfbee7ac091478119    Documentation
100755 blob 1b4624c876dae8f38f7c9e13f82d11b6ead39c9b    GIT-VERSION-GEN
100644 blob c39006e8e7e5c5be2114b79d50135dc08e3d1aaa    INSTALL
100644 blob d38b1b92bdb2893eb4505667375563f2d6d4086b    LGPL-2.1
100644 blob a1d8775adb4b38a0340cd7d04184915f0ee65d28    Makefile
```

Each tree entry gives a mode, object type (implicit from both the mode and from the underlying object), the underlying object's hash ID, and a path-name component.  For a file in some directory, the component is the file's name; for a sub-tree, the component is the directory's name.  Recursively traversing all the `tree` objects lets Git build up the full path name for each file, and when checking *out* a commit, Git does this recursive travel to build up the components of the *index*.  (We can mostly ignore the index but it's essentially the recursively-expanded and hence flattened tree, which Git can use to get the full path names for files.)

The actual file contents are stored in *blob* objects, so to view the content of the file named `COPYING`:

```
$ git cat-file -p 536e55524db72bd2acf175208aef4f3dfc148d42 | head -3

 Note that the only valid version of the GPL as far as this project
 is concerned is _this_ particular version of the license (ie v2, not
```

So, to summarize the above:

- All objects have hash IDs.  The actual hash ID is just a cryptographic checksum of the object's content (including the type-specifier at the front, so that if you make a blob out of a commit, the blob has a different hash ID from the commit—this means that the type of the object can be stored inside the object).
- Branch *names* identify specific commits, by their hash ID: for instance, `master` = `468165c1d8a442994a825f3684528361727cd8c0` (at the moment).
- Commits have one *tree* object, which has files and/or sub-trees by hash ID.  Recursively enumerating all the sub-trees and collecting all the file hashes gets us the snapshot content (hash ID only; we must still extract the actual blob text to get the real content).
- Commits have zero or more *parent* commits.

#### Normal commit adding and pushing

So with this we can see how commits normally grow.  We start with a single root commit, with no parents, and a name like `master` that identifies that commit:

```
A   <--master
```

Then we make a new commit: after `git add`ing new blobs to the index, we have Git package up the current index as a new tree object, write out the hash ID of the root commit as the `parent` line, write out ourselves as author and committer with "now" as the two timestamps, write out our log message, and turn the whole thing into a new commit object, which gets a new and unique hash ID.  Our new commit `B` has `A` as its parent, so if we write the new commit's hash ID into `master`, we get:

```
A <-B   <--master
```

Repeat long enough and you have a long chain of commits, ended by the commit to which a branch name like `master` points.  You can now `git push` these commits to another Git repository if you like: your Git sends to them *all* the commits that you have that they don't, e.g., if their `master` ends at commit `B` and you added `C` through `G`, your Git sends those five commits, along with any tree and file objects that they use that aren't already found in either `A` or `B`.

#### Using `--amend`

What `--amend` does *does not* change any existing commit.  If we already have a chain like:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

and we run `git commit --amend`, Git just makes a new commit `D` as usual, with one exception: **The parent(s) of the new commit is / are the parent(s) of the current commit.**  That is, the new commit `D` points back to the *same* commit(s) that `C` uses:

```
     C
    /
A--B--D   <-- master
```

The commit object `C` itself, along with the tree and any sub-trees and file blobs for commit `C`, are all *still in the repository*.  They will remain there until something comes along to remove them.  (The garbage collector, `git gc`, will *eventually* remove them, once there are no names for them.  But our Git will have *reflog entries* providing hidden names and thus protecting them for a month or so, so they will stick around at least that long.)

Let's suppose the server, wherever it is, also has commits `A` and `B`.  If we `git push` now, our Git will call up the server and, in effect,<sup>1</sup> get from it the hash ID that its `master` represents.  That tells our Git what commits, and hence trees and blobs, *they* have, which tells our Git what our Git should send.  In this case, that's just commit `D` and any of its related objects that (we think) the server Git lacks.

This all still applies even if we're "amending" a root commit.  Amend just means *use the current commit's parents for the new commit*, so if we have just one commit `A` and we "amend" it, we get:

```
A  (shoved aside)

B   <-- master
```

After figuring out which commit(s) to send and any necessary supporting objects, our Git packages them up into a *pack file*, which gets extra compression—that's what all the *counting objects* and *compressing objects* output is about—and sends the pack file, which the receiving Git expands back out as necessary.

The key here is that the pack file has *only* the necessary objects—or more precisely, those our Git *assumes* are necessary, based on commits and other objects found while traversing our commit graph from the commits we specifically told our Git to push, excluding those commits their Git has told told us that they have.

---

<sup>1</sup>In this example, our Git can literally do this.  However, in more complex cases, our Git won't necessarily have all commits that are the tips of *their* branches.  In that case, the usual protocol uses have/want exchanges, by commit hash IDs, to figure out which commits to send and which the other end already has.

---

#### Not all transfer methods are equal

The above all applies to figuring out what objects to send.  To make it work, our Git must converse with the server Git, to find out what the server has.  That's the normal (https or ssh based) push system, but not all transfers use such a system.  [The Pro Git Book has a chapter on the standard "dumb" and "smart" protocols,](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols) and mentions that push always uses the smart protocol.  So as long as your Git is using the smart protocol and you don't accidentally ask it to send objects that are not at the tip of your single-commit `master` branch, you will only send the objects you care about.

But what if someone has optimized things since the last time we did this analysis?  What if there's a *new* protocol that realizes that *their* Git has nothing at all, that *your* Git has already packed all objects into a good pack file, and that there's a huge amount of network bandwidth, and so just sends them that pack file?  They may get *all* your objects, including ones you (believe you) amended away.  It won't happen today, but what about tomorrow?

You don't *have* to worry about this.  It is almost certainly safe, and even future optimizations probably will be careful not to hand over lingering objects like this.  But how much are you willing to count on it?